# How to escape '?' while querying issues in a repo?

Tags: r, github, escaping

From the documentation of the package `gh`

> Issues of a repository

```
gh("/repos/hadley/dplyr/issues")
```

However, retrieves only the open issues. How to I get all issues?

I tried adding `\?state\=all` but I get

```
gh("/repos/hadley/dplyr/issues\?state\=all")
```

> Error: '\?' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting
>   ""/repos/hadley/dplyr/issues\?"

Comment: Try using \\ instead of just \

Comment: it's `gh("/repos/:owner/:repo/issues?state=all", owner = "hadley", repo = "dplyr", .token = tk, .limit = Inf)`

Comment: @Dambo, soon (I'm not sure what the time window is) you can post the answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing `\` was enough to avoid the error (I got stucked cause I was trying to escape it instead):

```
gh("/repos/:owner/:repo/issues?state=all", owner = "hadley", repo = "dplyr", .token = tk, .limit = Inf)
```